# JSF Eclipse Designer

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

Is there any Eclipse plugin that will allow me to do a Visual Studio like drag-and-drop for JSF components on a web page? So I won't have to write `<f:input...>` and the tool would just create this code for me?

If not eclipse, are there are other options?

(I do not plan to actually use something like this but I do need to know).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mat be the **[JSF page Designer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Visual_Page_Designer)** (or now "Web Page Editor") could do what you want?
It is illustrated in this [myeclipse page](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-14.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [myeclipseide.com](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/jsfdesigner_overview/images/vpd_overview_editor_layout.gif))</sub>

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/wtp-jsf-dev/msg00319.html), you can make the Visual Page Designer the default editor for JSP pages

> The JSF Tools Project-contributed Web Page Editor is NOT registered as the default editor for JSP files.
>   You can make the WPE the default editor for JSP files by following these steps:

- Navigate to `"Window" -> "Preferences..." -> "General" -> "Editors" -> "File Associations"`
- In the "`File types`" section, select "`*.jsp`"
- In the "`Associated editors`" section, select "`Web Page Editor`"
- Select the "`Default`" button

Comment: I have used MyEclipse for some years.  It is nice to get things done quickly, but it tends to creak quite a bit when you reach out in the corners - especially when using Pulse.   It may be better these days :)

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for and it was right there under my nose :-). Do you know if i can use it with richfaces? can i add my own custom UIComponents to the Palette?

Comment: @Nir Levy: I am not familiar enough with that plugin to know about its customization capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

The best for you is WPE in Eclipse. Read this http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsf/docs/tutorial/JSFTools_1_0_tutorial.html