# design JSF pages in Eclipse runing on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsf, tomcat

I am trying to find a way to design `JSF` pages in `Eclipse` instead of writing all the tags. I found in `Eclipse` market a plugin for `Jboss` and it requires `Jboss` server to run on it which is not in my case where I am using `Tomcat` server.

The Question is: Does any one know any way to design the `JSF` page in ***drag and drop way*** instead of the writing the tags. wither a plugin or another tool as long as I can use this design easily in `Eclipse`.

I am using `Spring` + `JSF` + `Tomacat`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971629/jsf-eclipse-designer , or at least the same answer.

Comment: I wonder how that is going to work when you add something like Primefaces. Creating web content using drag & drop, I already get tired and pain in my fingers just by thinking about it. Writing the text content (which often involves lots of copy/pasting) is so much less work.

Comment: The JBoss Tools plugin suite provides very neat JSF editor and you can deploy your projects on any supported by Eclipse server.

Comment: @nitind I already check this thread the are using (my Eclipse) which different than (Eclipse). For many reason I can not go with my (Eclipse)

Comment: @AdrianMitev it is nice but it only works with (Jboss) server not with other servers . In my case I am using (Apache Tomcat).

Comment: That's not true at all. Just use the JBoss Tools editors and deploy your app to Tomcat.

Comment: @user3227212 The editor shown is part of the Eclipse Web Tools Project. The JBoss Tools may offer a better one.

Comment: @AdrianMitev if it is possible, it will be great. But, are you sure about that because it shows in the requirement section the  need of Jboss server. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Where do you see that? Just create a new web project with jsf support, edit your pages using jboss tools editor and deploy your project to tomcat.